# QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission issue while my app doesn't contain it

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-play-console

My old version of my app contained QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission but after the Google email sent to me saying that I can't use this permission in my app so I deleted it and I check if my apps still have the permission or not and I'm sure that my app does not have the permission and Google still accepting my app with QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission issue saying that I must not use the permission that I already deleted.

you can check if I missed anything from screenshots in the bottom

[release details from google play console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLCDG.png)

and

[permission from a device after installing the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZZ5v.png)

I also tried to add the following line to my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove" tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />
```

Comment: Are you using "Internal Testing", "Closed Testing", or "Open Testing" release tracks? If these tracks still contain versions of the app that use this permission, you'll need to create new releases to supersede those versions.

Comment: yes you are right I'm using Internal Testing with that permission I will try it.

Comment: It's work. You can write this as an answer to be clear for others what was the solution in my case.

Comment: @GavinWright I'm not able to add a new build without that permission to the internal testing environment, since it is there in production

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, you need to also check your "Internal Testing", "Closed Testing", and "Open Testing" release tracks. If these tracks still contain versions of the app that use this permission, you'll need to create new releases to supersede those versions.

Also, understand that you might still get a rejection email even after you've updated all release tracks. This is because the automated review might finish for one track before the others. So the review fails because it's not yet considering the new versions on your other release tracks.

Comment: We updated all testing channels but still got rejected... waiting for Google to reply. : ( Do you know any other possible reasons?

Comment: Maybe the permission is in one of your dependencies? Check your merged manifest.

Comment: if automated review fails. Do I release yet another version or wait?

Comment: what do you mean by "you'll need to create new releases to supersede those versions"? i used fastlane to push to the internal track but get rejected due to QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES which is not in my android manifest

Comment: @m_wer It means that you need to submit an update to each release track that you've previously used. This will ensure that `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` isn't contained in any of your release tracks.

Comment: I've removed `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission everywhere, but still, my last production build has it which doesn't let me submit the current build for review, any idea what to do? @GavinWright