# Action requested - Submit the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission declaration by July 20

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, android-permissions, google-play-console

Here is the email I received from Google Play. I added `QUERY ALL PACKAGES` permission to the manifest file so that all the features would function properly in Android 11 or later. But in reality, I simply require a portion of the permission to implement those functionalities. So, if the "QUERY ALL PACKAGES" permission is withdrawn and another core permission is added in manifest file, do we still need to submit a permission declaration?

> DEVELOPER UPDATE
>
> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> If your app requires the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission, you need to
> submit the declaration form in Play Console by July 20. Otherwise, you
> will not be able to submit new apps or app updates.
>
> Action required:
>
> 1. If your app does not require use of the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission, you must remove the permission from your app manifest.
> 2. If your app requires use of the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission, you’ll need to provide a description and short video of the core
>    feature in your app that requires this permission. To prepare for the
>    questions you’ll need to answer, review this Help Center article.
>
> You have until July 20 to submit the declaration or remove the
> permission from your app manifest. Apps that fail to meet the policy
> requirements or do not submit the declaration form may be removed from
> Google Play starting July 20.
>
> Thank you for continuing to partner with us to make Google Play a safe
> platform for you and your users.
>
> Thank you,
>
> The Google Play team

Comment: Please let me know if you found any solution for this

Comment: @RutvikGumasana Please try below solution if it may help

Answer (score 0):

Try these solutions if you don't need QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73104066/10657559
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72774358/10657559
3. [Updating an app that has sensitive permissions on the Google Play Console](https://flutterhq.com/questions-and-answers/2907/updating-an-app-that-has-sensitive-permissions-on-the-google-play-console)

In my case I have submitted declaration form in play console like below

1. Go to Google Play Console , under Policy area -> App Content ->  click Manage button under Sensitive permissions and API

[image]

2. Here lists all sensitive permission used in our app -> click Manage button under corresponding permission

[image]

3. Fill the declaration form

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have submitted this 3 weeks ago and I haven't met with any issues from Google Play Console so far.

Comment: I can't see the Sensitive permissions and APIs under app content ???

Answer (score 0):

Thanhal's answer is almost very complete ... the one thing missing is that you HAVE to fill in a video URL, even though it is not marked with an asterisk denoting it compulsory!

As soon as you fill in a (mock) URL you can finally save the form.