# Crossed the July 20 deadline to Submit the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission declaration - what to do?

Tags: flutter, google-play, android-permissions

My current version app in play store has query_all_packages permission which I don't use.

I recently visited Play store only to find out that I cant update my app without submitting the permission declaration for query_all_packages

I don't use this package and am ready to remove it but how can I publish this update now as Google is not taking my update for review

Someone please help me find a solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try any of the solutions mentioned in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73287593/10657559

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment from @Thanhal and explanations [here](https://flutterhq.com/questions-and-answers/2907/updating-an-app-that-has-sensitive-permissions-on-the-google-play-console)

Try to complete the `Data Safety` section without going into sensitive API for  `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` and reupload a new build, it will drive the `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` away