# Problem with QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES in play console

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

i have an APP published in play store. This APP has a lib that uses the **QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES** permission.

So, i remove this permission in my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"
    tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />
```

After that i uploaded a new version to the play console, but it still keeps saying that the **QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES** permission is present.

My new build: **3603**
[image]
[image]
Note that the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission does not exist in this build

It seems that somehow the problem is still being associated with the previous version where it still had the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission.

[image]

ps: BUILD 3494 is a older build

In short, I can't upload a version with updated permissions, because it still asks to fill in the form to use QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES, even removing this permission.

can anyone help?

Comment: Seemingly having the same issue. My release tracks don't have the required permission and I've uploaded a build with the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES "removed" in the manifest. Google still gives the same error and will not let me replace the version. It seems that because the production build is live that the app is caught in limbo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue as well, I ended up following this user's recommendation [Updating an app that has sensitive permissions on the Google Play Console](https://flutterhq.com/questions-and-answers/2907/updating-an-app-that-has-sensitive-permissions-on-the-google-play-console) . I checked the app functionality, in the description I said I didn't need the functionality anymore with my newest release. I uploaded a bogus youtube video link. After about 5 min I was able to release the newest version without the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission.

Comment: Since the link is down, here you have the archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20220811110813/https://flutterhq.com/questions-and-answers/2907/updating-an-app-that-has-sensitive-permissions-on-the-google-play-console

Answer (score 2):

I believe this question describes the same problem, and it was answered.

[QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission issue while my app doesn't contain it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72764839/query-all-packages-permission-issue-while-my-app-doesnt-contain-it)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same issue because of my third party packages using **Query all packages permission** to Solve this
If you are using linux or unix based os then just go to location where flutter third party packages are installed in my case loaction is
**~/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org**

Just run the following command in terminal

grep -r QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES *

this will gives all packages pubspec.yaml file path that uses **query all packages permission** remove or replace that packages

Answer (score 1):

According to google policy your All active Bundle versions need to be compliant as per google policy,
You just need to update the new version and increase the version number of Your App in all the production and testing(Internal/closed/Open) if any to deactivate the versions using QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES.
Follow this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwTefutgXSU