# I Cant Open Flutter URL Via Link

Tags: flutter, dart, url-launcher

Flutter ,My Launcher is not working With Link Widget of Url Launcher.

```dart
final websiteUri = Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev');

          Link(
            uri: websiteUri,
            target: LinkTarget.blank,
            builder: (context, openLink) => TextButton(
              onPressed: openLink,
              child: Text(websiteUri.toString()),
            ),
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

use `launchUrlString` from the **url_launcher** package instead:

```
final websiteUri = 'https://flutter.dev';

onpressed:launchUrlString(websiteUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my AndroidManifest.xml , according to: https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#android and https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases#check-browser-available

and finally i add thi to AndroidManifest.xml like:

```
 <queries>
  <!-- If your app checks for SMS support -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="sms" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app checks for call support -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent>
  <!-- Place inside the <queries> element. -->
<intent>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent>
</queries>
```

It worked Perfectly no issues

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! You can absolutely do it.
for this you have to used [url_launcher: ^6.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

I just updated my AndroidManifest.xml.

```
    <!-- For Url Launcher -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
    <queries>
        <!-- If your app opens http URLs -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
        </intent>
        <!-- Check for brouser available in device  -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app makes calls -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your sends SMS messages -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app sends emails -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your application checks for inAppBrowserView launch mode support -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

And you can launch your url like this way.

i just make method for launch url.

```
Future<void> url({
  required String url,
  LaunchMode mode = LaunchMode.platformDefault,
  WebViewConfiguration webViewConfiguration = const WebViewConfiguration(
    enableJavaScript: true,
  ),
  String notLaunchMsg = "Unable to open url",
  String errorMsg = "Something went wrong",
}) async {
  try {
    final uri = Uri.parse(url);
    final willLaunch = await canLaunchUrl(uri);
    if (willLaunch) {
      await launchUrl(
        uri,
        mode: mode,
        webViewConfiguration: webViewConfiguration,
      );
    } else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: notLaunchMsg);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint('catchError : $e');
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: errorMsg);
  }
}
```

And you can called like.

```
     onTap: () => url(
            url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYxRYB1oszw",
            // mode: LaunchMode.inAppBrowserView, //inside your app
            // mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication, //Device browser application -> youTube App
            // mode: LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication,
            // mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView, // inside app web view
          ),
```

**Update**

**Note**

remove below line from AndroidManifest.xml as we mention above, because it will give error while app publish in play store, without this permission app will work fine. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73071518/problem-with-query-all-packages-in-play-console).

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

***New way and easy way to implement***

i just make simple class with required property.

```
class UrlLaunch {
  /// Default function -> This will handle all try of launch activity
  /// if its possible to launch then launch otherwise it will toast an errorMsg
  /// This function make private because prevent access outside from class
  Future<void> _myUriLaunch({
    required String url,
    LaunchMode mode = LaunchMode.platformDefault,
    WebViewConfiguration webViewConfiguration = const WebViewConfiguration(
      enableJavaScript: true,
    ),
    String notLaunchMsg = "Unable to open url",
    String errorMsg = "Something went wrong",
  }) async {
    try {
      final uri = Uri.parse(url);
      final willLaunch = await canLaunchUrl(uri);
      if (willLaunch) {
        await launchUrl(
          uri,
          mode: mode,
          webViewConfiguration: webViewConfiguration,
        );
      } else {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: notLaunchMsg);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('catchError : $e');
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: errorMsg);
    }
  }

  ///! Launch un url

  Future<void> urlLaunch({
    required String url,
    LaunchMode mode = LaunchMode.inAppBrowserView,
    String notLaunchMsg = "Unable to open url",
    String errorMsg = "Failed to open url",
  }) async =>
      await _myUriLaunch(
        url: url,
        mode: mode,
        notLaunchMsg: notLaunchMsg,
        errorMsg: errorMsg,
      );

  ///! send mail

  Future<void> mail({
    required String email,
    String? subject,
    String? body,
    String notLaunchMsg = "Unable to send mail",
    String errorMsg = "Failed to send mail",
  }) async =>
      await _myUriLaunch(
        url: Uri(
          scheme: 'mailto',
          path: email,
          query: '''subject=${subject ?? ''}&body=${body ?? ''}''',
        ).toString(),
        notLaunchMsg: notLaunchMsg,
        errorMsg: errorMsg,
      );

  ///! send SMS

  Future<void> sms({
    required String mobile,
    String? body,
    String notLaunchMsg = "Unable to send sms",
    String errorMsg = "Failed to send sms",
  }) async =>
      await _myUriLaunch(
        url: Uri(
          scheme: 'sms',
          path: mobile,
          query: '''body=${body ?? ''}''',
        ).toString(),
        notLaunchMsg: notLaunchMsg,
        errorMsg: errorMsg,
      );

  ///! Call

  Future<void> call({
    required String mobile,
    String notLaunchMsg = "Unable to dial call",
    String errorMsg = "Failed to call",
  }) async =>
      await _myUriLaunch(
        url: Uri(
          scheme: "tel",
          path: mobile,
        ).toString(),
        notLaunchMsg: notLaunchMsg,
        errorMsg: errorMsg,
      );

  ///! WhatsApp

  Future<void> whatsApp({
    required String mobile,
    String? msg,
    String countryCode = '91',
    String notLaunchMsg = "Unable to open whatsapp",
    String errorMsg = "Failed to open whatsapp",
  }) async =>
      await _myUriLaunch(
        url: Uri.parse(
          "https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=$countryCode$mobile&text=${msg ?? ''}",
        ).toString(),
        notLaunchMsg: notLaunchMsg,
        errorMsg: errorMsg,
      );
}
```

How to used this class???

```
...

     ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => UrlLaunch().urlLaunch(url: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74324458/i-cant-open-flutter-url-via-link/77357132#77357132"),
              child: const Text("Url"),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => UrlLaunch().mail(
                email: 'sahil078078@gmail.com', // required
                body: 'I am learning flutter', // optional
                subject: 'Learn', // optional
              ),
              child: const Text("Email"),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => UrlLaunch().call(mobile: "9988776655"),
              child: const Text("Call"),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => UrlLaunch().whatsApp(
                mobile: "0000000000", // mobile number
                msg: "This msg send with url launcher", //Optional
              ),
              child: const Text("WhatsApp"),
            ),

...
```

Hope this will help you.