# Flutter app reject again and again in Play Store for REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-play, google-play-console

I build flutter application and i tried to publish application in Google Play Store but application reject many time for same reason maintioned in below image

[image]

I use open_file package and this package contain **REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES** permission so i tried with remove permission for this package .xml file and also to remove package and upload but still application get rejected.

All permission use in application are below any body tell me for which permission it will reject every time.

[image]

Below screenshot for **rejected status with detail notes**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with QUERY\_ALL\_PACKAGES in play console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73071518/problem-with-query-all-packages-in-play-console)

Comment: @Jabbar Thanks for suggestion but i solve my issue using google support

Comment: Hello @RaviLimbani Can you please let me know how you resolved the issue using google support? I am facing similar issues. My app gets rejected again and again even after replacing package.

Answer (score 1):

**One of your dependency contains that dangerous permission**
delete the dependency which contains that permission
if your yaml file contains

```
open_file:
```

remove that dependency it contains that permission

Comment: Thanks for replay. I tried with remove open_file dependencies from project and then tried to upload but it sill reject in play console

Comment: check all dependencies where native code is implemented than remove that dependency

Comment: I also check all dependencies but no one contain this permission except open_file. But i don't know why is this reject.

Comment: when you upload again the latest build is it shows any warnings can you share warnings screen shot?

Comment: Sure you can check in question

Comment: that is rejection email when you upload before sending in testing or sending in production google also shows some warnings can you sent that screen shot