# PlayStore rejected my Flutter App due to QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission

Tags: android, android-manifest, flutter-plugin, merged-manifest

Playstore rejected my Flutter app due to below issue.

> **Issue found: Less broad app-visibility method should be used**
> We are unable to approve your app’s use of QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission because the declared task can be done with a less broad app-visibility method.

I tried many times, eventhough Playstore still rejecting my Flutter app.

I Checked my `Manifest` file.
And also I checked each and every line in the `Merged Manifest File`.
But I never find the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission and none of my plugins also seems using the permission. Please help to get rid of the problem.

*Your help will save my day*

My Manifest file `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.example">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.android.chrome" />
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <application
        android:label="Example"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />



        <service
            android:name=".firebase.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

> Merged Manifest File

https://streamable.com/k57m0y

My `pubspec.yaml` file

```
version: 1.0.3+4

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.1 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  icons_launcher: ^2.0.1
  get: ^4.6.5
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.8
  url_strategy: ^0.2.0 # remove # symbol from the flutter web
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  connectivity: ^3.0.6
  http: ^0.13.3
  animated_bottom_navigation_bar: ^0.3.3
  intl: ^0.17.0
  permission_handler: ^9.2.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.12
  geocoding: ^2.0.1
  geolocator: ^8.2.1
  flutter_switch: ^0.3.2
  firebase_messaging: ^11.2.8
  firebase_core: ^1.21.1
  file_picker: ^4.1.6


flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/app_logo1.jpg"

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
```

Comment: That merged manifest you posted is just a log of what went in there, not the actual merged manifest.  Worst case, you can get that by opening the apk (its a zip file) and reading the manifest from in there and looking for the permission.  But one of those manifests mentioned there almost certainly has that permission in it.  Either that or your toolchain is adding it.

Comment: I added my merged manifest. Check now

Comment: This question has already been answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73071518/problem-with-query-all-packages-in-play-console

Comment: I tried all answers

Comment: if you are trying to replace a track in production, you need to change the gradual release to 100%. Only then your version is approved

Comment: App got released after removing  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0